# c++ function in namespace won't work?

Tags: c++

This is weird and I'm trying to find the reason why would the first call to `Draw` on the object `shape` is fine while the second call to Draw on the "text" field will work only when supplying the prefix of the namespace? (ie `Shapes::Draw`) :

```
#include <iostream>
namespace Shapes
{
    class Shape {
        public:
            Shape() {}
            virtual void InnerDraw() const {
                std::cout << "Shape\n";
            }
    };

    class Square : public Shape {
        public:
            void InnerDraw() { std::cout << "Square\n"; }
    };

    void Draw(char* text) { std::cout << text; }

    void Draw(const Shape& shape) {
        Draw("Inner: ");
        shape.InnerDraw();
    }

    Shape operator+(const Shape& shape1,const Shape& shape2){
        return Shape();
    }
}


int main() {
    const Shapes::Square square;
    Shapes::Shape shape(square);

    Draw(shape); // No need for Shapes::
    Draw("test"); // Not working. Needs Shapes:: prefix

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Google König-lookup – sorry, Koenig-lookup to be precise

Comment: [Argument Dependent Name Lookup](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Argument-dependent_name_lookup)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For `Draw(shape)` the compiler looks in the namespace where `shape`s type is defined to see if there's a matching function named `Draw`. It finds it, and calls it. For `Draw("test")` there is no namespace for the argument, so nowhere else to look. This is called **argument dependent lookup**, ADL for short.

Comment: Comment's gone. I didn't see two calls in `main`. Completely misunderstood the question due to the red herring within one of the `Draw` overloads. Bit drunk.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit - go out for a drive. You're in no shape to write code. `<g>`

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit We'll forgive you this time. Bottoms up!

Answer (score 2):

This is called [Argument-dependent lookup](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Argument-dependent_name_lookup). When an unqualified function is called, the compiler consults the namespaces for all of the arguments to the function and adds any matching functions to the overload set. So when you say `Draw(shape)` it finds `Shapes::Draw(const Shapes::Shape& shape)` based on the `shape` argument. But when you say `Draw("test")`, the argument `"test"` has no namespace, certainly not the `Shapes::` namespace that is required.

Comment: ADL also applies if a _function_ **can** be found in scope at the call sight. Functions found by ADL are added to the overload set.